# What is different between Bucket cache accesses/hits and cachingAccesses/cachingHits stat?

Tags: hbase, amazon-emr

Below is the Hbase L2 Block cache stats.  Can someone explain the difference between accesses/hits and cachingAccesses/cachingHits? I can't find documentation for the block cache stats. It would be helpful if you can send me a pointer for the public documentation.

2023-05-14 04:41:48,190 INFO  [BucketCacheStatsExecutor] bucket.BucketCache: failedBlockAdditions=33782252, totalSize=449.18 GB, freeSize=87.58 GB, usedSize=361.60 GB, cacheSize=252.57 GB, accesses=26627851, hits=20151051, IOhitsPerSecond=0, IOTimePerHit=NaN, hitRatio=75.68%, cachingAccesses=1324950, cachingHits=1009868, cachingHitsRatio=76.22%, evictions=60, evicted=37847879, evictedPerRun=630797.9833333333